# OEM account after recovery from Dell XPS ( preinstalled UBuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, dell, reboot, recovery-mode, oem

Today i tried to create my account on my newly purchased laptop ( dell xps with ubuntu 14.04 preinstalled in it) . After creating my account, i got a error like system program problem detected and it enabled me to stay in my account. I rebooted it into recovery and now i opened my laptop with an account named like OEM and it wants a password from me whenever i try to do something. I have no idea what this OEM account is . I did not create it and  do not even know what this password is. How can i create my own account?

I am pretty new on ubuntu and my knowledge is not so good on it. It would be so nice if you give me some ideas about it.